# TypeORM Many-to-Many join table extra column

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

I've a simple many to many relationship with TypeORM

#### User Entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @ManyToMany((type) => Organization, (organization) => organization.users)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'user_organizations',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'user_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'organization_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
  })
  organizations: Organization[];
```

#### Organization Entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'organizations' })
export class Organization {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany((type) => User, (user) => user.organizations)
  users: User[];

}
```

My goal is to create a relationship which not only defines which user relates to which organisation it should also contains information in which role the user is related to a organisation. My idea was to extend the relation table with an extra `role` column for that.

```
create table user_organizations(
  user_id varchar(64) not null,
  organization_id varchar(64) not null,
  role varchar(64) not null,
  foreign key (user_id) references users(id),
  foreign key (organization_id) references organizations(id),
);
```

My question is how to store the role in the database. Currently I'm doing something like this.

```
let user = new User();
let organization = new Organization();
organization.name = name;
organization.users = [user];
organization = await this.organizationRepository.save(organization);
```

How can I fill also the `role` column via TypeORM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach to this kind of problem is to create a separate table solely for `Role` and then refer to this table in the `user_organizations`.

But think of this scenario - what if a user doesn't have just one role? It can and does happen. That being said, my suggestion would be handling the role **outside** of the `user_organisations` table. Since the table is **M2M**, the primary key will be a composite of `User.ID` and `Organisation.ID`. My suggestion would be:

1. Create separate table for all roles (like Users or Organisations)
2. Create M2M table between `Roles` and `UserOrganisations`